# How to use OpaquePointer in a Function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm using a framework in my project and for one function it requires an OpaquePointer!.

Which OpaquePointer do I set and how?

The Answer below, how to set the opaque, is accepted by xcode but crashed when you put `self` or `session!` in there, even if you put `try?` in front.

I'd prefer in Swift if that's possible, else just in Objective-C.

The function which I want to use:

```
session?.attemptConnection(withSessionPointer: <#T##OpaquePointer!#>)  //Session is a variable where I set the Usern/Passw IP and stuff like that.
```

The Framework I'm using: [**TOSMBClient from CocoaPods**](https://cocoapods.org/pods/TOSMBClient)

This is the Swift rendering of:

```
- (NSError *)attemptConnectionWithSessionPointer:(smb_session *)session;
- (NSError *)attemptConnection;    //This also exists in the Framework and would be ideal, but doesn't work at all. So it doesn't recognize it.
```

> According to the [GitHub Docs](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOSMBClient/blob/284418d2e2ea2c89077bc71c37c71eed3edf49ae/TOSMBClient/TOSMBSession.m), I don't need a `SessionPointer` at all or `self` should be enough, but it doesn't work.
>
> Regarding Mohammad Sadiq Answer: Its works to put `self` or `session` in with his method, but it will always crash.

Comment: Did you check the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/opaquepointer) of `OpaquePointer`?

Comment: What framework is it? What is the actual API we're dealing with here?

Comment: @matt Its the TOSMBClient from CocoaPods

Comment: @DávidPásztor I did and I can't figure out how exactly I need to set it

Comment: So this is Swift's rendering of `- (NSError *)attemptConnectionWithSessionPointer:(smb_session *)session;`

Comment: @matt I guess so

Comment: Most probably, it is the Swift mapping of a pointer to an "incomplete type". – But anyway: Do you have a `smb_session` object? Can you pass that as argument?

Comment: OK but then your `session` property _is_ the `smb_session *` in question.

Comment: @MartinR see https://github.com/TimOliver/TOSMBClient/blob/284418d2e2ea2c89077bc71c37c71eed3edf49ae/TOSMBClient/TOSMBSession.m

Comment: @matt Yes the session is a variable where I set the Passwort, IP and stuff

Comment: @matt I've seen it, but what do I put in Qpaquepointer? According to these docs I don't need it at all but i do. My intent is to check if the Password is right - thats why I'm trying to attempt a connection

Comment: [There's indeed an `attemptConnection()` method](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOSMBClient/blob/284418d2e2ea2c89077bc71c37c71eed3edf49ae/TOSMBClient/TOSMBSession.m#L59) that doesn't take a session pointer argument (it uses the one that the instance holds); what happens when you try and call that?

Comment: @Hamish Thats what I ment in my question with "should not be neccassary at all" but it doesn't work - It doesn't autocomplete and you can't build for whatever reason

Comment: @JimCatron that might be a problem to bring to the attention of the developer of this API — it needs some serious revision in any case

Comment: @matt I know this is not perfect, I believe this was from C wrapped to ObjC and now I'm using it in Swift, just because there is no other way to do SMB operations in ObjC or Swift at the moment, so this is my only hope.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever object you would like to pass to function you can use following conversion

```
UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```

The above will convert `self` to OpaquePointer. You can convert your own object. 
In your case you would require `session` to be converted and passed.

The next point. Though might not be of use to you right now. 
Many such functions return back the pointer reference. In those cases you can retrieve back using

```
let myObject = Unmanaged<ObjectClass>.fromOpaque(returnedReference!).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Comment: OpaquePointer.init(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())) ... :). Try this one in your case.

Comment: Actually you might not need to convert to UnsafeMutableRawPointer just try using OpaquePointer.init(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

Comment: Actually it does work so Xcode lets my Build it but, the method always fails.

Comment: If i put session or self in, it crashes regardless if the usern/passw is correct. Only if the Wifi is not connected, it will return this error and then crash.